# How do I run a line of code after a function that contains setState when it is finished updating state?

Tags: reactjs, setstate

How do I run anotherFunction() after myFunction() finishes in the child component without putting it inside of myFunction()? anotherFunction() will have a separate concern but is dependent on myFunction() having  updated state first. Or maybe I have this completely structured wrong? Help is appreciated

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
 constructor() {
  super()
  this.state = {/*...*/}
 }
 myFunction = () => {
  //...
  this.setState(/*...*/)
 }
 anotherFunction = () => {
  //...
 }
 render() {
  return (
          <Child
           myFunction={this.myFunction}
           anotherFunction={this.anotherFunction}
          />
         )
 }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
 constructor() {
  super()
 }
 render() {
  return (
   <button
    onClick={() => {
     this.props.myFunction()
    }}
   >
    My Button
   </button>
  )
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) accepts a second argument as callback which gets fired after the `state` is successfully changed. Try something like this:

```
 myFunction = () => {
  //...
  this.setState(/*...*/, ()=>this.anotherFunction())
 }
 anotherFunction = () => {
  //...
 }
```

Comment: Thanks but anotherFunction() has a different concern than myFunction(). Isn't it considered bad practice to do it this way?

Comment: I don't think it's considered as bad practice if you want to invoke `anotherFunction` only if `state` is changed inside `myFunction`. In this cases, `callback` becomes useful, check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function

Answer (score 0):

so setState does provide a callback func after it updates the state.

so in your case call another function like this and it will be fired after setState is completed.

```
 myFunction = () => {
  //...
  this.setState(/*...*/, ()=>this.anotherFunction())
 }
 anotherFunction = () => {
  //...
 }
```

Hope this helps, feel free for doubts

Answer (score 0):

setState can have a callback :)

```
this.setState({ name: "changed"}, ()=>{console.log(this.state.name)})
```